# Push segue lags target VC's code execution

Tags: ios, xcode, push, segue

Anybody else experience this?  From my home view I push segue to a playback view.  I'm playing back some audio bits that should be coordinated with some labels.  Problem is, the audio starts before the segue finishes, so my first few labels don't get a chance to appear.  Even seems like the audio playback is delaying the segue.  This happens both on the simulator and the iPhone.

Comment: The code to start your audio is in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Not directly, but called from there, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling your code from `viewDidLoad`. Put the code to start your audio in `viewDidAppear:animated` instead.

Here's the order in which view controllers load views:

- loadView
- viewDidLoad
- viewWillAppear:animated
- viewDidAppear:animated

viewDidAppear:animated gets called after the animation is complete.

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  That improved it.  The view was still lagging in viewWillAppear, but it's good in viewDidAppear.